# CKEditor: Uncaught TypeError: switchEditors.switchto is not a functiononclick

Tags: plugins, posts, editor

Only the buttons  `Add Media`, `HTML` and `Visual` show up after installing **CKEditor for WordPress**.

In addition, encounter the following error while clicking to `HTML` or `Visual` by using the tool `Inspect element`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: switchEditors.switchto is not a functiononclick 
@ post-new.php:529
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ, not yet. actually, I switched to markdown editor.